# How to convert 100 into ONE ZERO ZERO not ONE?

Tags: java

I have to call a method which is converting number to words and two others methods which are reversing and getting count of entered number and have to call both in first method but in case of number 100 it is  giving output as ONE but it should give ONE ZERO ZERO.So my confusion is how to call count method in converting number method and to make give output as ONE ZERO ZERO with simple calling because I am using intelliJ and a beginner So I have to find out how to call get count method in first method which is number to word.

```
public static void numberToWords(int number) {
    if (number == 0) {
        System.out.println("Zero");
    } else if (number < 0) {
        System.out.println("Invalid Value");
    }

    int revInteger = reverse(number);
    while (revInteger != 0) {
        int modulus = revInteger % 10;
        revInteger /= 10;

        switch (modulus) {

            case 1:
                System.out.println("One");
                break;

            case 2:
                System.out.println("Two");
                break;

            case 3:
                System.out.println("Three");
                break;

            case 4:
                System.out.println("Four");
                break;

            case 5:
                System.out.println("Five");
                break;

            case 6:
                System.out.println("Six");
                break;

            case 7:
                System.out.println("Seven");
                break;

            case 8:
                System.out.println("Eight");
                break;

            case 9:
                System.out.println("Nine");
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}


public static int reverse(int reversedNumber) {
    int revNumber = reversedNumber;
    int digit = 0;
    while (revNumber != 0) {
        int n = revNumber % 10;
        digit = digit * 10 + n;
        revNumber /= 10;
    }
    return digit;
}

public static int getDigitCount(int number) {
    int count = 0;
    if (number > 0) {
        while (number != 0) {
            number /= 10;
            ++count;
        }
        return count;
    } else if (number == 0) {
        return 1;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you try adding a `case 0:` for the `modulos`

Comment: This looks like you're trying to get some help solving HW. I would suggest putting a breakpoint and debugging it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the reverse of the number 100 is 001, which is just 1. However, there's a trick you can pull, where you append 1 (via number*10 + 1) to the number before reversing it, and then terminate when the number remaining is 1 (of course you could append any non-zero digit, but 1 is as good as any). For example, in the case of 200 you'd reverse 2001, which is 1002. When you've output Two Zero Zero you're left with 1, so terminate.

```
int revInteger = reverse(number * 10 + 1);
while (revInteger != 1) {...}
```

However, you also have to handle the 0 case in your switch statement:

```
case 0:
  System.out.println("Zero");
  break;
```

With these two changes your code works.

```
int revInteger = reverse(number * 10 + 1);
while (revInteger != 1)
{
    int modulus = revInteger % 10;
    revInteger /= 10;

    switch (modulus)
    {
    case 0:
        System.out.println("Zero");
        break;
    case 1:
        System.out.println("One");
        break;

    // snipped cases 2-8

    case 9:
        System.out.println("Nine");
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: but by these condition output is shown in endless loop.

Comment: I've shown the full code. I've snipped out the cases handling 2 to 8.

Comment: yeah I've figured this out and it did work but  it have to show invalid value also when we enter any negative number so when i entered number -222 it has given me endless loop.

Comment: You'll need to return after printing "Invalid Value" when the number is negative.

Answer (score 3):

Instead case blocks you can use a pre built map to replace your digits with word as below

```
public class NumToWord {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        numberToWords(100);
    }

    public static final String[] numToWord = new String[10];
    static {
        numToWord[0]="Zero";
        numToWord[1]="One";
        numToWord[2]="Two";
        numToWord[3]="Three";
        numToWord[4]="Four";
        numToWord[5]="Five";
        numToWord[6]="Six";
        numToWord[7]="Seven";
        numToWord[8]="Eight";
        numToWord[9]="Nine";
    }
    public static void numberToWords(int number) {
        String numberStr = number + "";
        for (char a: numberStr.toCharArray()) {
            String word = numToWord[Integer.parseInt(a+"")];
            if(null!=word) {
                System.out.println(word);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Personally, I'd use an array instead of a map here.  But the table-driven approach is definitely the way to go!  +1

Comment: @FoggyDay Agree implementing the above solution with Array instead map would be bettter option

Answer (score 0):

Obligatory Java 8 Streams code:

```
private static final Map<Character, String> MAP;
static {
    Map<Character, String> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put('0', "ZERO");
    map.put('1', "ONE");
    ...
    MAP = Collections.unmodifiableMap(map);
}
```

```
public static String numberToWords(int number) {
    String numStr = String.valueOf(number);
    return IntStream.range(0, numStr.length())
        .mapToObj(i -> MAP.get(numStr.charAt(n.length() - 1 - i)))
        .collect(Collectors.joining(" ");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

And a few other solutions.

The first one simply initializes the array and constructs the string backwards via concatenation.  It uses the `remainder operator (%)` to index into the array.

```
int n = 100;
String[] digitWords = { "ZERO", "ONE", "TWO", "THREE", "FOUR",
        "FIVE", "SIX", "SEVEN", "EIGHT", "NINE" };

String s = "";
while (n > 0) {
    s = digitWords[n % 10] + " " + s;
    n /= 10;
}

System.out.println(s);
```

Or using Java Streams.  This simply iterates successive integer quotients and then applies the `remainder operator` to stream the appropriate array element. The individual elements are once  again assembled in reverse using a reduction operation.

```
n = 100;
String str = IntStream.iterate(n, i -> i > 0, i -> i = i / 10)
        .mapToObj(i->digitWords[i % 10]).reduce("", (a,b)->b = b + " " + a);
```

Both methods print

```
ONE ZERO ZERO
```