# How to convert a number into its respective letter in web component java script

Tags: javascript, html

Hello a type text input that when writing a number writes the corresponding text one below the other
example

123 ..
one
two
three
...

111
one
one
one
...
825
eight
two
five
123
one
two
three
111
one
one
one

I base myself on that function but I don't know how to do it
If someone could help me thank you very much

```
const tmp= document.createElement('template');
tmp.innerHTML=`
    <div>
    
    
    <input type="text" placeholder="Tercer componente" onkeyup="remplacenumber(this)"  />

    <label miPropiedad="" />

    </div>

`;



function remplacenumber(e){
    e.value = e.value.replace(/[1-1000]/g, "")
  }


class Numeros extends HTMLElement{

    

    constructor(){
        super();
         this._shadowRoot=this.attachShadow({'mode':'open'});   

    }

}
window.customElements.define('neo-numeros',Numeros)
```

Comment: well given the way you want to do it, theres only ten numbers so you could use an object to match each number to each word.`{ "1": "one", "2": "two", ...}` or even an array and use the index to pick out the word. `["zero", "one", ...]`

Comment: Have a look at this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61858307/how-to-convert-100-into-one-zero-zero-not-one/61858638

Answer (score 0):

as suggested in comment since you just want to print the number better user an array containing the string for number and use the index position of number in that array to create the string representing your number in alphabetical form

```js
var numtoStrarr = ["zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine"]

function returnNumberAsString(numberInput) {
  var numSplit = numberInput.toString().split('');
  var stringArr = [];
  numSplit.forEach(x => stringArr.push(numtoStrarr[x]));
  return stringArr.join(' ');
}
console.log(returnNumberAsString(100));

console.log(returnNumberAsString(1130));
```

Answer (score 0):

For my point of view :

```js
const output = document.getElementById("numbersOutput");

function replaceNumber(input) {
  const numbersInLetters = ["zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine"];
  let numbers = input.value.split("");
  let newNumbers = numbers.map((n) => numbersInLetters[parseInt(n)]);
  output.innerHTML = newNumbers.join(" ");
}
```

```html
<input type="number" placeholder="Enter a number" onkeyup="replaceNumber(this)" />
<p id="numbersOutput"></p>
```

You still use your HTML input area.

- `numbers` is an array of string that contains your input.
- `newNumbers` is an array of strings that contains the numbers converted to the worded one.

Comment: Thank you very much for the code
I wanted to adapt it to my code and it is throwing an error in "innerHTML"
the error says component.js:44 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you are looking for:

```
const numberToWordsBank = ["zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine"];

const numberInput = document.getElementById("number-input");
const words = document.getElementById("words")
const updateTranslation = document.getElementById("update-translation")

updateTranslation.addEventListener("click", () => {
    words.textContent = '';
    for (const number of numberInput.value) {
        words.textContent += numberToWordsBank[number] + ' ';
    }
});
```

The HTML (change script.js to the name of your javascript file):

```
<input id="number-input" type="text" />
<button id="update-translation">update</button>
<p id="words"></p>

<script src="script.js"></script>
```